# Checkbox not getting check until second time clicked

Tags: android, checkbox

I have group of four checkboxes in my activity,

[All, option1, option2, option3].

My intended functionality is that All is selected as default when the activity is loaded up, if you select any of the other options, [All] will be un-checked, and if you have any of the other options selected and you select [All] again then it will uncheck the other options.

I have this sort of working, All is selected as default, however when I select one of the options; All is unchecked as desired, but the selected checkbox does not become checked until I press the checkbox for a second time.

Similarly if I have option 2 and 3 checked, and I select All: options 2 and 3 are unchecked but All doesn't check until I press it for a second time.

Here is my onCreateMethod

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selection);

    all = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.All);
    option1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.option1);
    option2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.option2);
    option3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.option3);


    IfAllChecked();
    optionOneSelectedUnCheckedAll();
    optionTwoSelectedUnCheckedAll();
    optionThreeSelectedUnCheckedAll();

}
```

Here is my code for when All is selected:

```
private void IfAllChecked() {
    all.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {


            if (option1.isChecked()) {
                option1.setChecked(false);
            }

            if (option2.isChecked()) {
                option2.setChecked(false);
            }

            if (option3.isChecked()) {
                option3.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    }
    );
}
```

Code for when one of the options is checked

```
private void optionOneSelectedUnCheckedAll() {
   option2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (all.isChecked()) {
                all.setChecked(false);
              }

        }
    }
    );
}
```

This is my Layout, I set All to be true here.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/UnitName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/All"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="All"
            android:checked="true" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/option1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dun L"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/option2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Blackrock" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/option3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dundrum" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Hopefully someone will understand what im trying to explain.

Comment: Do you have the code to set the OnCheckedChangeListeners wrapped in those functions (IfAllChecked(), optionOneSelectedUnCheckedAll()) in your code as well?

Comment: Your post is a little confusing. You describe an Activity with four Checkboxes, but your code shows _six_ Checkboxes.

Comment: Sorry, it was very late when I posted this question, I had changed the names of the variables as it would be easier for people to follow, Ive edited my question to correctly change all the names

Comment: Ok, as long as you changed the appropriate variable names, my answer should be good. Lemme know if you've any questions or can't get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, your description doesn't really match the code you've provided. Also, it is unclear where the methods you've shown are called. If, indeed, you're layout contains the mentioned `all`, `option1`, `option2`, and `option3` `CheckBoxes`, then the following code should behave as you've described.

In your `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selection);

    all = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.All);
    option1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.option1);
    option2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.option2);
    option3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.option3);

    all.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {    
            if (b) {
                option1.setChecked(false);
                option2.setChecked(false);
                option3.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });

    option1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(optionCheck);        
    option2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(optionCheck);        
    option3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(optionCheck);        
}

final CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener optionCheck = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {    
        if (b) {
            all.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I've edited my answer so the onCreate() method is correct to your situation.

Comment: Just to add to this, incase it isn't clear the problem was that I wasn't using at "setOnCheckedChangeListener()" thats the key. Thanks again Mike M